# addEventListener programmatically is null

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, winjs

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.type = "button";

button.className = "button";
button.innerText = "OK";
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("Hello!");
}, false);
```

When I do this, the button never gets that event listener. I've tried `attachEvent`, `button.onclick`, and nothing seems to work. The button shows up fine with the class and text.

EDIT: So basically what I'm trying to do is programmatically show a "popup" array of divs.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/98VLx.png, and I set it up like this: `var x = new JMTK.Custom.MessageDialog()`, then to add a popup, I just type `x.addMessage({template: {type: JMTK.Custom.MessageDialog.templates.alert, title: "Alert title", message: "This is a message here", button1: {text: "Hello"}}})`

This is the `addMessage()`:

```
var content = document.createElement("div"); 
//htmlObject.template is the object that has all the info, 'this' is the scrim element that contains each "white" popup"
content.innerHTML = MessageDialogClass.html.alert(htmlObject.template, this).innerHTML
```

which calls this function:

```
alert: function (template, element) {
    //Array of functions
    var callbacks = MessageDialogClass.callbacks;

    var alert = document.createElement("div");
    var id = Date.now();
    alert.id = id;
                
    var header = document.createElement("h1");
    header.innerText = (template.title ? template.title : "ALERT");

    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.innerText = (template.message ? template.message : "No message specified")

    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.type = "button";

    button.className = "button";
    button.innerText = (template.button1.text ? template.button1.text : "OK");
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (template.button1.callback) {
            template.button1.callback();
        }

        //MessageDialogClass.popElement(id);
        //delete callbacks.id;
    }, false);

    alert.appendChild(header);
    alert.appendChild(paragraph);
    alert.appendChild(button);

    callbacks.id = alert;

    return alert;
},
```

But again, when I click on the button, nothing happens, and in the DOM Explorer there is no `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Did you add the element to the DOM?  What browser (older versions of IE don't support addEventListener)?

Comment: Yes as I said the class/text show up  `alert.appendChild(button);` where alert is my outer div, no error messages anywhere. In the DOM Explorer in Visual Studio 2012, the onclick event just isn't there.

Comment: There is something you are disclosing to us because the general concept works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gdKKD/

Comment: I'll edit my original post with the full details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was creating a `div` in my 'alert' template, and then setting the innerHTML of another div to that div. So it wouldn't allow me to set the event listener because it wasn't part of the DOM.

So instead of doing

```
var content = document.createElement("div"); 
//htmlObject.template is the object that has all the info, 'this' is the scrim element that contains each "white" popup"
content.innerHTML = MessageDialogClass.html.alert(htmlObject.template, this).innerHTML
```

I just did

```
var content = document.createElement("div"); 
//htmlObject.template is the object that has all the info, 'this' is the scrim element that contains each "white" popup"
content = MessageDialogClass.html.alert(htmlObject.template, this).innerHTML
```

because `alert` is returning a `div` already. So yeah, it had to do with setting the innerHTML rather than just setting it equal to the DOM node.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what your solution might be. You've provided good detail about what you *want* to do with the button click, but I'm afraid there's something else at play. I wonder if you have an element in front of the button that keeps it from receiving the mouse click. I see you're in a WinJS project for Windows 8. You have really good dev tools in VS2012. Break just after you add the button to your DOM and go to the DOM Explorer and see if you find the button. Go to the JavaScript Console and see if you can access the button. See if you can add an event listener manually there. Try adding the button manually in your markup and then see if adding an event works. Hope one of these gets you to the solution. Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need append your button before set the event listener.

Comment: Nope, that wouldn't cause the issue.

Comment: I don't figure out how the browser can construct the message queue if the object isn't attached.

Comment: You can bind events to elements before the element is inserted into the DOM. In fact, it's a best practice. If you can avoid DOM traversal while binding events, then you should do so--more efficient.

Comment: New for me, thank @ElliotB. BTW I actually use element.onclick and always I believe that the handler will be attached in the moment the element is appened.